# pip version conflict and unable to install packages in python2.7.6 & 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

When I was trying to install any packages using pip and pip3 I got below error:
Also tried to remove and reinstall pip, but got same error.any idea how to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 444, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 725, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 632, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 9.0.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==1.5.4'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.4
```

Comment: I had this issue. I overcame it by uninstall python 3 and re install python 2.7. Two versions of python in a single system may lead to version conflicts. So try removing any one version. Hope it works

Comment: I got this when i type 'pyth' autocomplete:                                               python             python2.7-config   python3.4          python3.5-config   python3-config     
python2            python2-config     python3.4m         python3.5m         python3m           
python2.7          python3            python3.5          python3.5m-config  python-config'